# How can I pass data to the onStateChange event handler with Youtube iframe API

Tags: javascript, data-binding, youtube, event-handling, dom-events

I am building a small video player with Javascript for a website. I have a list with videos in JSON. I instantiate my player with

```
var Videoplayer = new myVideoPlayer(data);
```

Because the list contains videos from Vimeo and YouTube, I want to handle both APIS inside this object. Inside I have functions like:

```
setVideo(videoId)
```

to select and play a video, or

```
markVideoAsSelected(video)
```

to add classes in html.

So far everything went pretty smooth, but I am hitting a wall now. When I load the YouTube player via the API, I add the:

```
events : {
    'onStateChange': self.YTonStateChange
}
```

Everything I want is bound to the **Videoplayer** instance I created in the beginning. On state change, I run this:

```
YTonStateChange : function(e){
    var self = this
    switch(e.data){
        //Video ended code 0
        case 0:
            setTimeout(self.switchToNextVideo, 3000);
        break;
    }
}
```

**The problem**:

`this` is now bound to the event from the YouTube API and I lost my object. I don't know, how I can pass my object instance along with the event to the event handler?! There are things in there that I need for further steps, how can I get it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the context to 'self' like that :

```
events : {
    'onStateChange': self.YTonStateChange.bind(self)
}
```

It will force 'this' value to 'self' in the YTonStateChange callback. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, in addition to [R. Foubert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40114150/5113030), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) may be used since `ECMAScript 2015`:

```js
YTonStateChange: e => {
    switch(e?.data) {
        case 0: {
            setTimeout(this.switchToNextVideo, 3000);

            return;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```